# What's exactly the issue with this PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am experimenting with PHP and MySQL, but now I found a PHP code that I want to use, but it's vulnerable for SQL injection. Does anyone know what the injection is and what code can fix it?

```
    <?
        // both the username and password must be specified
        if(!isset($_GET["username"]) || !isset($_GET["password"])) {
                print "NO username and/or password";
                die;
        }
        $username = $_GET["username"];
        $password = $_GET["password"];

        // prepare database connection
        mysql_connect("host", "user", "password");
        mysql_select_db("dbase");

        // validate the specified username
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

        if(!$res || !($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))) {
                print "Unknown username";
                die;
        }
        // validate the password
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = ".$row[0]);
        if(!$res || !($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))) {
                print "Illegal userid record";
                die;
        }
        if($password != $row[0]) {
                print "Invalid password";
                die;
        }
        // Access Granted
?>
```

The code is part of an extra code but that one isn't necessary, the username can be selected with  /somecode.php?username=' OR '1'='1&password=something but '  OR doesn't work with the password, could anyone help me?

Regards

Comment: Did you look up SQL injection?

Comment: (There's a good primer at xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Why are you using antiquated `mysql_*` functions. Use PDO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not build your SQL code dynamically - pass user input as parameters.

See [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in the PHP documentation.

If you dynamically build your SQL like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

where `$username` could contain something which was directly provided by a user, then you are at risk. Using a solution such as a prepared statement, where it is not possible for a user to directly influence the actual SQL query being executed, is a safer alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
    // validate the specified username
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Since $username is directly from the user someone could pass in a username of `test' OR id='1` which would yield the following sql:

SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'test' OR id='1';

The attacker has now become the user with id 1. Oops!

You need to escape the `$_GET['username']` variable with `addslashes()` or something comparable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with that code:

- you are using outdated API. Instead of the ancient `mysql_` function you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) with *prepared statements*.
- there is an SQL injection waiting to happen

Instead your code should looks something like this:

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbase;host=127.0.0.1', 'user' , 'password' );
$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );

$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :user');
$stmt->bindParam( ':user', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 128);

if ( $stmt->execute() )
{
    var_dump( $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ));
}
```

Additional reading:

- [Introduction to PDO](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3qMh8k_v2U8J%3awww.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk)
- [Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)